# Authenticating ChatBot (Microsoft Bot Framework) using cookies from different website in same domain?

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, direct-line-botframework

I need to authenticate my user in chatbot ,using cookies in my website
eg. I have a website "portal.b.com" hosted on an azure Virtual Machine  ,

So when my user logs into my website I cookies are stored 
When he/she clicks On the bot , the bot should be aware about the user details.

eg. Hi "User_Name"

1) I have apis to get the user details , 
2) I just dont want to ask user to sign in separately into the bot.
3) I use a session id and other cookies in my website
4) I have currently implemented the bot in Node JS
5) I have web application in C#

How can I implement above scenario?

Thanks

Comment: isn't the cookie passed along with the request to chat bot website ? maybe you need to add some kind of rule to allow the origin of your website so you can pass cookie and around and also match the session is.

Comment: I am not sure if I can write a custom api over the bot sdk to accept website's session id.
Also somewhere , I will need a mapping of website's session id with bots conversation id.